# How to disable 'Save As' option and prohibiting file saving in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: security, read-only, password-protection, read

I'm seeking guidance on how to implement restrictions in Adobe Acrobat for a PDF document.

I have password-protected the file, but I'm looking to further restrict users from accessing the 'Save As' option and also prevent them from saving the opened file locally.

Is there a way within Adobe Acrobat to disable the 'Save As' functionality for a password-protected PDF? Additionally, is there a method to prevent users from saving the document after opening it, even if they have the password to access it?

I've tried exploring the security settings in Adobe Acrobat, but haven't found a direct solution for this particular issue. Any insights, tips, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It really would be pointless, since if one can *view* the file, one can take a *screenshot*, either from the device itself, or with a camera. And if one has access to the file to *view* it, one can *copy* it.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, not within the PDF file itself. Your only options are:

- **Restrict view permissions:** require a password or manage the file system/sharing permissions
- **Restrict edit permissions:** make it read-only with signatures or file permissions for example.

Anyone who can read a file will be able to copy it.

The Adobe Acrobat desktop app does not have an option to disable saving locally, since it **must** have files locally in order to view them.

---

There are other tools for storing and viewing documents that do not allow copying, screenshots, saving, etc. but that is generally classified as data loss prevention (DLP) software - often used in healthcare/finance industries. Adobe Acrobat does not have these features.